# can't compare "iterator" i with std_logic_vector inside for generate

Tags: vhdl

Inside a **for generate** construct, I'm trying to use **i** in a comparison, but I'm having trouble.

The code is:

```
mult_lineA_colX :
for i in 0 to DIM-1 generate
begin
    if i /= to_integer(unsigned(iterNb)) then
        multVect(i) <= A_line(i) * X_mat(i);
    else
        multVect(i) <= (others => '0');
    end if;
end generate;
```

Context:

```
type A_line_type is array (0 to DIM-1) of std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0);
signal A_line : A_line_type := (others=>(others=>'0'));

type X_type is array (0 to DIM-1) of std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0); 
signal X_mat : X_type := (others=>(others=>'0'));

type multVect is array (0 to DIM-1) of std_logic_vector (DATA_SIZE*2-1 downto 0);
```

Libraries:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
```

I'm having an error on the condition line:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "/path/to/file.vhd" Line 213: Syntax error near "if".
```

Isn't this use of **i** permitted? How can I fix this or change it to something of the same effect?

I've also tried using a **when** constructor for the same effect but I get this two erros:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:56 - "/path/to/file.vhd" Line 211: <i> is not a signal.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:258 - "/path/to/file.vhd" Line 211: Cannot convert type integer to type multvect
```

Answer (score 1):

VHDL '93 does not support if-then-else constructs outside a process. The next best thing you can do for generate statements is something like this:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity foo is
end entity foo;
architecture bar of foo is

begin  -- architecture bar

  multV: for i in 0 to DIM-1 generate
    constant compare : boolean := (i /= to_integer(unsigned(iterNb)));
  begin
    case_1: if compare generate
      multVect(i) <= A_line(i) * X_mat(i);
    end generate case_1;
    case_2: if not compare generate
      multVect(i) <= (others => '0');
    end generate case_2; 
  end generate multV;
end architecture bar;
```

Comment: multVect is declared as a label here and can't be used as a signal assignment target, just like in the snippets of the question it is declared as a type and not a signal.  As you point out an iteration scheme if condition must be a static expression. which means the value of iterNb at the time your constant compare is declared, making it the default value from the iterNb declaration expressed as an integer.

Comment: The lack of signal declaration of type multVect was a serious oversighting. Thanks for that! I'm having trouble with the initial value for the constant not being constant at all (as it should not, since I'll want this to change this over time). Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Comment: So interNb is not constant? I am not sure what you want to achieve here, but in this case you should not use generate statements at all (since these are evaluated at compile time) but a process.